# Forgot to attach travel itinerary

Tags: visas, uk

I forgot to attach travel itinerary.

Biometric details are taken.

I submitted other documents but not travel plan.

What is the procedure to send travel plan to UK embassy in my country(India).

I was informed not to attach air ticket so did not upload. I took tickets with me buy embassy people did not ask anything about it. I also forgot to inform them.

By travel plan I mean details mentioning from which date to which date I am planning to visit UK.

Comment: You shouldn’t even have bought those tickets.

Comment: Can you tell me what to do now?

Comment: What do you mean by "travel plan"? What is the document that was not submitted?

Comment: I should mention from which date to which date I am planning to stay in UK. This is what I am calling as travel plan.. @michael Hampton

Comment: AFAIK the dates of travel are among the very first questions the application asked. So it's possible you already put them in, but forgot about it. In that case no separate document is needed.

Comment: I don't remember saying anything about dates...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Oh yes... I see the application. There was a column "Date you plan to arrive in the UK" I mentioned there 2 and July. Then there was a column asking how many days do you want to stay? I said 16 days... I think that should be fine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As several questions in the application form deal with arrival date and duration of stay in the UK, you have already entered those dates.

There is no need to give the information again.

Comment: That is correct. It was not a problem, I got the visa and I came back to my country also :)